# Get Rewrite rules to be ignored on specific URL's

Tags: .htaccess

I have re-created a site from WordPress in native PHP, and have added certain ReWrite rules in the .htaccess to mimic the WP URL's, but I need to add a couple of reWrite rules to beautify a couple of URL's.

I tried creating 2 directories and having separate .htaccess files in each directory, but to no avail.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#Beautify new URL's
RewriteRule ^operating-areas/([^/]+) town.php?place=$1
RewriteRule ^operating-area/([^/]+)/([^/]+) keyword.php?place=$1&keyword=$2
```

**www.domain.com/operating-areas/London**

needs to be sent to

**myPage.php?place=London**

and then

**www.domain.com/operating-area/London/Finance**

needs to be sent to

**myOtherPage.php?place=London&keyword=Finance**

At the moment I am getting 'Too many redirections'.

The rules I have used for the WordPress styling were found on the internet, hence my limited knowledge of this subject hinders me from stopping them firing in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all of your code with this block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

#Beautify new URL's
RewriteRule ^operating-areas/([^/]+)/?$ town.php?place=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^operating-area/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ keyword.php?place=$1&keyword=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

`/?$` at the end of the pattern allows matching of an optional `/` at the end. It is also important to keep this rule before `.php` adding rule.

Comment: Now, what if I wanted to use WordPress purely for the blog function in a blog folder? I have just tried to install it, and at the /blog/wp-admin/setup-config/setup-config/?step=1 stage I get another too many redirects error.

Comment: When you install WordPress in Blog directory then it will have a separate htacceas in Blog directory which will override parent htacceas

Comment: Yes, works now, I deleted my .htaccess file, installed WORDPRESS and then put my .htaccess file back, and all seems well.